# Exception when installing MSIX on Windows Server 2022

Tags: msix, windows-server-2022

I tried to install a Msix package on Windows Server 2022 and got the following to stdout. I created it with Visual Studio as x64 Release. I followed the shown link, but it only says, that I should speak with the producer of the package which is me. What can I try/ which information can I offer that helps? I could successfully install that package on Win10/11 X64.

> PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test> .\Install.ps1

> Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?
> File C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test\Install.ps1 is published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US and is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
> [V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D"): A
> Found package: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test\MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.msix
> Found certificate: C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test\MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.cer

> Before installing this app, you need to do the following:
> - Install the signing certificate
> The certificate was successfully installed.

> Installing app...
> Found dependency package(s):
> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1.msix
> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test\Dependencies\x64\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1.msix
> Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF9, Install failed. Please contact your software vendor.

> Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20 from:  (MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.msix)  failed with error 0x8000000B. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

> NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] ec302b94-92c8-0000-eca2-30ecc892d901 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID ec302b94-92c8-0000-eca2-30ecc892d901

> At C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1:487 char:13

- ```
          Add-AppxPackage -Path $DeveloperPackagePath.FullName -Dep ...
  ```
- ```
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\Admini...0.12.0_x64.msix:String) [Add-AppxPackage], IOException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand

> Error: Could not install the app.  To ensure security, please consider uninstalling the signing certificate until you can install the app.  Instructions for doing so can be found here:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243053
> Press Enter to continue...:
> PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test> Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID ec302b94-92c8-0000-eca2-30ecc892d901

> Time                      ID           Message
>
> ---
>
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     157          The app package signature was validated for core content of the app package published by CN=userx. Payload won't be validated until the files are read.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     216          App manifest validation warning: Declared namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build is inapplicable, it will be ignored during manifest processing.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     216          App manifest validation warning: Declared namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/developer/templatestudio is inapplicable, it will be ignored during manifest processing.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     170          The streaming reader was created successfully for app package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     157          The app package signature was validated for core content of the app package published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US. Payload won't be validated until the files are read.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     170          The streaming reader was created successfully for app package Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1003.565.600.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     157          The app package signature was validated for core content of the app package published by CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US. Payload won't be validated until the files are read.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     170          The streaming reader was created successfully for app package Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1003.565.600.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     604          Started deployment Add operation on a package with main parameter MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.msix, dependency parameters Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1.msix, and Options ForceApplicationShutdownOption and 0. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     10002        Creating Resiliency File C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\30c4086b-5cf8-4276-8dad-eede09288a64_S-1-5-21-2033860306-2932684127-2157950611-500_1.rslc for Add Operation on Package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     607          Deployment Add operation on package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20 has been de-queued and is running for user SID S-1-5-21-2033860306-2932684127-2157950611-500.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     854          Successfully added the following uri(s) to be processed:  file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test/MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.msix file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test/Dependencies/x86/Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1.msix
> file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/MyApp_1.0.12.0_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1.msix.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     605          The last successful state reached was BundleProcessed. Failure occurred before reaching the next state Indexed. hr: 0x8000000B
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     401          Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20 from:  (MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.msix)  failed with error 0x8000000B. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
> 5/30/2023 10:12:34 AM     404          AppX Deployment operation failed for package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20 with error 0x80073CF9. The specific error text for this failure is: Deployment Add operation with target volume C: on Package 2E3B0916-381A-4433-8136-00C46100E96D_1.0.12.0_x64__728k65e6c1w20 from:  (MyApp_1.0.12.0_x64.msix)
> failed with error 0x8000000B. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.

I followed the link, but that did not help.